# Algebra Question 2

Tags: linear-algebra

John told Stan that he would keep tripling the amount of money Stan has if Stan would each time pay back $1.35 to John. At the end of the 3rd full payment to John, Stan had no money left. How much money did Stan start with?

This is how I solved it:

$3(3(x-1.35))=0$
$3(3x-4.05)=0$
$9x-12.5=0$
$9x=12.15$
$x=1.35$

So he started out with 1.35 dollars, gave John 1.35 dollars, so on the first payment he was left with zero dollars. So John tripled Stan's money, $3*0$, but he still has zero. The process goes on till the third payment is finished and Stan still has zero dollars

Comment: (I am endlessly amazed that people like Stan agree to these things... but, yes, ... #innumeracy... sad, but visible in current politics, too.)

Comment: I see no trick and, more importantly, I see no question. What is the point of this post?

Comment: Look more carefully at "the process continues". After John tripled Stan's money and, as you said, Stan still had zero, Stan was required to pay another 1.35 dollars to John, so Stan's wealth goes negative at this point. See how it continues from there.  Also, you seem to assume that the process begins with Stan making a payment. The wording of the problem ("pay **back**) indicates to me that John triples Stan's money first, and **then** Stan pays 1.35 dollars.

Comment: Interpreting the  phrase "tripling the amount of money Stan has" when Stan is in debt is indeed tricky.I don't think it would be interpreted as tripling Stan's debt by the "man on the Clapham omnibus".

Answer (score 0):

It's a real algebra problem, not a trick, since as @AndreasBlass comments, he pays back the first $\$1.35$ only after the first tripling.

If you set up the equation correctly you'll see that he starts with $\$13A/27$ if he has to pay back $\$A$ each time. For a numerical answer to the problem, let $A=1.35$.

You can generalize the problem in several ways if you note that $1 + 3 + 3^2 = 13$.

Comment: The difference between algebra problems and real life is that 135 is divisible by 27.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's _one_ of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

The OP either read the question incorrectly, or made a mistake in setting up his equations.  If Stan started with 1.35 dollars, then after tripling that and then paying back 1.35 stan has 2.70.  If he keeps doing that he will end up with something other than zero.

The correct answer, showing what Stan has after each step, is
$$
x \\ 3x \\ 3x-1.35 \\ 9x-4.05 \\ 9x - 5.40 \\ 27x - 16.20 \\ 27 x - 17.55 \\27x - 17.55 = 0 \implies x = 0.65
$$
Stan started with 65 cents.